# How to get a consistent WeakSet length during finalization?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, weak-references

Consider the following code which uses a `WeakSet` at the same time as a finalizer:

```py
>>> import weakref
>>> import gc

>>> class A:
...     pass

>>> class Parent:
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a

>>> ws = weakref.WeakSet()
>>> def finalizer(a):
...     print(f"Finalizing {a}")
...     print(f"Contents of the WeakSet: {ws}")
...     print(f"List of elements in the WeakSet: {list(ws)}")
...     print(f"Length of the WeakSet: {len(ws)}")
```

Consider the following example:

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> p = Parent(a)
>>> ws.add(p)
>>> weakref.finalize(p, finalizer, a)
<finalize object at 0x1c2ca0d7060; for 'Parent' at 0x1c2ca0aff40>

>>> del p
>>> gc.collect()
Finalizing <__main__.A object at 0x000001C2CA239310>
Contents of the WeakSet: {<weakref at 0x000001C2CA270090; dead>}
List of elements in the WeakSet: []
Length of the WeakSet: 1
```

When swapping the creation of the finalizer and the addition to the `WeakSet`, on the other hand:

```py
>>> a = A()
>>> p = Parent(a)
>>> weakref.finalize(p, finalizer, a)
<finalize object at 0x1c2ca0d7060; for 'Parent' at 0x1c2ca0aff40>
>>> ws.add(p)

>>> del p
>>> gc.collect()
Finalizing <__main__.A object at 0x000001C2CA519370>
Contents of the WeakSet: set()
List of elements in the WeakSet: []
Length of the WeakSet: 0
```

Why are these results different? Is there a way to get a consistent value for `len(ws)` as the object is being finalized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation contains the reason why this is happening, in a roundabout way.

In [weakref.finalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.finalize) (emphasis mine):

> When the program exits, each remaining live finalizer is called unless its atexit attribute has been set to false. **They are called in reverse order of creation.**

The hidden consequence of that lies in the fact that calling `WeakSet.add` will register a finalizer under the hood. Consequently, in the first case, our own finalizer will be called before the `WeakSet` is updated in the reverse order of creation ; in the second case, the `WeakSet` is updated before the finalizer.